# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I'm creating a blog with the help of http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/32-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step. Adding a new blog post is going great, but everytime when I want to post a new comment I get the following error:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<div id="comments">
        <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
</div>

<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

the error i'm getting:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#show 
Missing partial comments/_comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Reuzellf/quick_blog/app/views"
```

Ruby is completely new for me, I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Sorry, I posted to soon

Comment: There seems to be a problem with : <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>

Comment: Did you seen this line **`You'll now need to create a file called app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb with the following contents`** in the **`link`** which you attached?

Answer (score 1):

That is a shorthand.

Rails will look at the object in this case `Comment` and go to the views for that object.

In this case it will look in `app/views/comments` for a partial called `_comment.html.erb`

So create the comments directory if it doesn't exist and then the partial with whatever you want each comment to display.